# S3 bucket policy to only allow V4 signed requests

Tags: amazon-s3

I have sever programmatic accesses to S3 buckets and, as of now, I have to implement something to only allow these requests to succeed if they use v4 signing.

will adding

```
"Condition": {
              "StringEquals": {"s3:signatureversion": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"}
             }
```

force the bucket to only accept v4 signing if the rest of the policy is for an allow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/bucket-policy-s3-sigv4-conditions.html), yes.

`{"s3:signatureversion": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"}` matches Signature Version 4.

`{"s3:signatureversion": "AWS"}` matches Signature Version 2.